# Restriction for wallpaper on windows 7 starter

Tags: desktop-customization

I am using windows 7 starter and i am unable to set my desktop background and when i right click on the wallpaper it does not show any option for 'set as desktop background' any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default those are disabled in Windows 7 starter

> By default the Windows 7 Starter and Windows 7 Home Basic editions do
>   not include the Personalization features such as change desktop
>   background, Desktop Slideshow, Screen Saver, and Windows Color and
>   Appearance.

[Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/47294-desktop-background-wallpaper-change-windows-7-starter.html) you can find more about it, and some work arounds.
Since I dont have Windows 7 starter, and I cannot check it I will give you a list of programs that will help you with your backgrounds.

- [Starter Background Changer](http://starter-background-changer.en.softonic.com/)
- [Oceanis Change Background W7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/47294-desktop-background-wallpaper-change-windows-7-starter.html) that you can found on firs page I linked you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the desktop background with Windows Starter Edition.

Source [Windows 7 Starter- what are the limitations?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-starter-what-are-the-limitations/422801d5-89de-494d-8cc1-6f4fc21c2ac0) :

**Windows 7 Starter does not include**:

- Aero Glass, meaning you can only use the Windows Basic or other opaque themes. It also means you do not get Taskbar Previews or Aero Peek.
- **Personalization features for changing desktop backgrounds, window colors, or sound schemes.**
- The ability to switch between users without having to log off.
- 64 bit version
- Multi-monitor support.
- DVD playback.
- Windows Media Center for watching recorded TV or other media.
- Remote Media Streaming for streaming your music, videos, and recorded TV from your home computer.
- Domain support for business customers.
- XP Mode for those that want the ability to run older Windows XP programs on Windows 7.